# Extract Text From Non Cpyable Pdf by python

Tags: python, pdf

I have been trying to extract text from PDFs , i am using PyPDF2 with python and extracting text but now i am trying to extract text from Non Copyable pdfs. it returns me empty string.

I am converting simple Copyable PDF to Non Copyable PDF online from here : https://online-pdf-no-copy.com/

here is my code :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


def get_info(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        if pdf.isEncrypted:
            pdf.decrypt('')
        page = pdf.getPage(1)
        # print(page)
        print('Page type: {}'.format(str(type(page))))
        text = page.extractText()
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'pdfs/finalNoCopy.pdf'
    get_info(path)
```

My Output :

```
Page type: <class 'PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject'>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

it gives me empty string .

Comment: When you say non-copyable pdf, you mean pdf's which can't be searched. In other words, they are scanned images. Am I correct ?

Comment: No , it's not like that. i can still select text in adobe acrobat but can't copy. Please upload any dummy pdf on that site , you will came to know what i means

Comment: so why do want to extract text from non copyable...why not do it from the normal PDF's?

Comment: I am extracting text from resumes they are mostly in pdf forms but i am thinking all possibilities

Comment: Try my answer, I hope this would work for any type of PDF's

Comment: they are copy protected PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
import fitz ## Pip install pymupdf

text1=""
file_path = r'your_file_name_with_path.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(file_path)
for page in doc:                            
    text1+=(page.getText())
```